# VirtualBox, enable audio, but prevent the host to listen to it?

Tags: virtualbox

Its a weird question I know! but let me explain:

-I'm building a radio over network for my call center.

-I have one server with 3 virtual machines, each with a different radio station in spotify.
-Running the software "[Stream What You Hear](http://www.streamwhatyouhear.com/)" I can stream those radio station through my network without a problem.

-But!! I hear the 3 stations at the same time if I use that server.

**¿Is there any way to enable audio so it can transmit, but prevent the host from hearing that audio?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disable host driver (set to null), but keep audio controller:

[image: screenshot]

Some info from [wiki](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Configuring_VirtualBox_Virtual_Machine_Settings):

> When audio is enabled, VirtualBox provides the option for a virtual
>   Intel ICH AC90 or a Creative Labs Sounds Blaster 16 sound card to be
>   configured in the virtual machine. For Linux guests, PulseAudio, OSS
>   and ALSO options are also available.
>
> The Host Audio Driver setting controls whether the sound is directed
>   **to the audio system of the host computer (so that it is heard) or sent
>   to a Null driver so that it is not heard on the host.**